# Conflict between tex4ht and biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, conversion, tex4ht, biblatex-chicago

I cannot get `tex4ht` to work with `biblatex-chicago`. Compile the MWE below with `pdflatex` generates the following errors:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)))

Package biblatex Warning: Language 'american' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using fallback language 'english' on input line 14.


! Package biblatex Error: Patching 'ifthen' package failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \begin{document}

? 

Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex)                Footnote detection will not work.

! Package biblatex Error: Patching \MakeUppercase failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \begin{document}

?
```

I tried loading `babel` with various options but this did not change anything.

**EDIT 1** My initial example was too minimal: I now realize the problem only occurs when trying to use these packages as part of a custom class.

**EDIT 2** The same error occurs when just loading `biblatex` with the `style=chicago-notes` option, so I have edited the MWE to reflect that. To simplify debugging, I've put `tex4ht` into the MWE so that you can just run `pdflatex` on it directly.

File `mwe.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2016/02/10 biblatex-chicago + tex4ht test]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[style=chicago-notes]{biblatex}
\endinput
```

File `bib4ht.tex`:

```
\documentclass{mwe}
\usepackage{tex4ht}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Sample,
author={Last, First},
title={Sample Book},
year=2016
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test.\cite{Sample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't load `babel` with a mere `english` as the option: choose `american` or `british` (or `canadian`, or ...).  Given that you hope to use `biblatex-chicago`, the most common thing to do would be to add `\usepackage[american]{babel}`.  Normally, I recommend loading `csquotes` too, but that is not needed to make your example work.  That is, your example plus `\usepackage[american]{babel}` makes `htlatex` fun without errors for me.

Comment: @jon That didn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, works for me: `babel.sty 2016/02/01 3.9o`; `english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p`; `biblatex-chicago.sty    2014/08/15 v 2.9a`; `biblatex2.sty 2015/12/22 v3.2`; `english.lbx 2015/12/22 v3.2`; 
`american.lbx    2015/12/22 v3.2`; `cms-american.lbx    2013/10/29 v 2.8`

Comment: @jon Thanks -- you're right. But my example was too minimal. See my edit.

Comment: Hmm, I get a very different error: `! Package biblatex Error: Patching 'ifthen' package failed.` (appears right after a `biblatex` warning that 'american' is not supported and that the package would fall back to 'english', which was just loaded.) Then errors for a failure to patch `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase`...

Comment: Also: I should mention: I assume `bib4ht.tex` is meant to be loading `mwe.cls`.

Comment: @jon Thank you for the correction. Yes, I get all those same errors.

Comment: I also get the errors about failed patching. Maybe you can update your question to reflect the actual error message you get, so people don't get confused.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I added more of the error messages.

Comment: what is strange that this error happens only when `biblatex` is loaded in the class file. It compiles correctly if it is used in the package or directly in the document

Comment: If you can manage to make the MWE even more minimal and reduce the overhead by not loading `biblatex-cicago`, but only `biblatex` maybe that can help those trying to track the problem down.

Comment: I get errors if I load `biblatex-chicago` with `\documentclass{article} ` and no other packages at all. If I also load `tex4ht`, I get a different error (the failure to patch `ifthen`) but the basic problem on my system is `biblatex-chicago` at all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Don't load `biblatex` from a class file when using `tex4ht`, unless someone can solve this problem. If I turn my class file into a package, it works fine.

`biblatex` with the chicago style option calls the package `biblatex2.sty`, and this file runs a series of tests on the class in order to patch certain commands. *I think* that when processing with `tex4ht` and using a custom class, for some reason `biblatex` doesn't get through these tests successfully.

---

*Below are notes from my investigation, which might be useful to someone who wants to actually answer the question. If you do, I'll gladly reward a bounty.*

I added`\usepackage{tex4ht}` and `\tracingall` to the `.tex` file and compiled with `pdflatex`. The place where the error is output happens just after line 1409146 of the `.log` file:

```
\@firstoftwo #1#2->#1
#1<-\csname etb@tgl@blx@tempa\endcsname
#2<-\etb@err@notoggle {blx@tempa}\@gobbletwo
{\csname}

\etb@tgl@blx@tempa #1#2->#1
#1<-\blx@err@patch {'ifthen' package}
#2<-

\blx@err@patch #1->\blx@error {Patching #1 failed} {This is an internal issue t
ypically caused by a conflict\MessageBreak between biblatex and some other pack
age. Modifying\MessageBreak the package loading order may fix the problem}
#1<-'ifthen' package

\blx@error #1#2->\begingroup \blx@safe@actives \PackageError {biblatex}{#1}{#2.
}\endgroup
#1<-Patching 'ifthen' package failed
#2<-This is an internal issue typically caused by a conflict\MessageBreak betwe
en biblatex and some other package. Modifying\MessageBreak the package loading
order may fix the problem
{\begingroup}
{entering semi simple group (level 1) at line 15}
```

All I can tell is that the error is issued because of some problem with the way `etb@tgl@blx@tempa` is being passed to `\@firstoftwo`.

---

The same error arises if I do what `biblatex-chicago` is doing internally, which is just to do `\RequirePackage[style=chicago-notes]{biblatex}`. `Biblatex.sty`, then, by default calls `biblatex2.sty`.

The `'ifthen'` error happens after line 135 of `biblatex2.sty`. It is issued when `\TE@hook` is undefined. The only package that defines that command (I grepped all of them) is `xifthen`. Loading `xifthen` before `biblatex` eliminates the `ifthen` error.

Now there is still the `footnote` error, which comes from after line 154 in `biblatex2.sty`. Here the package is checking to see which classes are loaded, and redefining the footnote commands as needed for each. When the footnote command is successfully patched, it sets `blx@tmpa` to `false`. If, after all the test, `blx@tmpa` is still true, then it prints this error message about the footnotes.

Comment: Can you reproduce with current Biblatex (which no longer includes `biblatex2.sty`)?

Comment: I can now reproduce this without a custom class and get errors even without `tex4ht`.

Answer (score 2):

As `tex4ht` patches some internal `biblatex` macros, it sometimes fails when these macros change in new `biblatex` versions. I reported this issue on [tex4ht bug tracker](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?273) and provided bugfix, which is now included in TeX distributions, so your sample compiles without errors with updated TeX Live, for example

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, after a TeXLive update. When was the bugfix added to TeXLive?

Comment: @AndrewCashner it worked for me, but probably because I modified your sample files. it fails again when I copy your current `mwe`

Comment: How did you modify them?

Comment: I removed direct including of tex4ht in the document and probably used `\usepackage[style=chicago-notes]{biblatex}`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have looked at the ticket in the tex4ht bug tracker and from what I understand, there is a patch file (biblatex.diff). Can someone explain where to copy this file or what to do with it?