# biblatex + TeX4ht

Tags: biblatex, tex4ht

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[notes, short, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\usepackage{endnotes}%
\let\footnote\endnote%
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{endnote}{chapter}%
\makeatother

\xapptobibmacro{cite:short}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {}
  {}

\bibliography{525-76472_6P}

\begin{document}

In a similar vein, Abolafia argues that ``market institutions are
produced and redefined as a result of the purposeful action and interaction of powerful interests competing for control.''\autocite[191]{Abolafia1996} Members, owners, and users of market organizations will forge formal or informal coalitions to attain their \cite{Abolafia1996} goals.


\backmatter

\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={BIBLIOGRAPHY}
]

\end{document}
```

%%% content of bbbl file%%%

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.8 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup

\refsection{0}
  \sortlist[entry]{cms/global/}
    \entry{Abolafia1996}{book}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=400ff12d316695feb92062860fedf647}{%
           family={Abolafia},
           familyi={A\bibinitperiod},
           given={Mitchel},
           giveni={M\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {Cambridge, MA:}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Harvard University Press}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{400ff12d316695feb92062860fedf647}
      \strng{fullhash}{400ff12d316695feb92062860fedf647}
      \strng{authornamehash}{400ff12d316695feb92062860fedf647}
      \strng{authorfullhash}{400ff12d316695feb92062860fedf647}
      \field{sortinit}{A}
      \field{sortinithash}{3248043b5fe8d0a34dab5ab6b8d4309b}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{title}{{Making Markets}}
      \field{year}{1996}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

%%%BibTeX source code:

```
@book{Abolafia1996,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {Abolafia, Mitchel},
    Publisher = {Harvard University Press},
    Title = {{Making Markets}},
    Year = {1996}}
```

I am converting the above code to HTML by using the command:

```
htlatex test "xhtml" " -cunihft" " -cvalidate -p"
```

No errors are shown, but the ouput does not comes in a correct manner. Please suggest how to achieve the HTML text equal to TeX output.

Comment: The redefinitions of `thebibliography` should not do anything for `biblatex`, can they be removed from the MWE? Do you need the `rotating` package? Are all the font changes relevant or can the issue be reproduced without them? Would it be possible to post the relevant `.bib` entries instead of the `.bbl`? The `.bbl` is tied to one specific `biblatex` version, so people with newer versions (like me) won't be able to make use of it. The `.bib` on the other hand is of course usable with all versions.

Comment: @moewe Modified the MWE as you said, thanks...

Comment: I get sensible output (MikTeX 2.9 fully updated, `tex4ht  2018-06-12-16:01`, `biblatex` 3.12 etc. pp.), but the compilation on the way throws errors about english not being a supported language (similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292268/35864).

Comment: I also checked the MWE with TeX live 2018 on Ubuntu 18.04. If I run `htlatex`, Biber and `htlatex` again I get a usable bibliography from your MWE. I do still get the errors about English, though,  should probably report that. Did you run Biber and can you show us a screenshot of the output you get from the MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a difference in the output of `tex4ht` and `pdflatex` on your sample file. But I got some compilation errors:

> Package biblatex Warning: Language 'english' not supported. (biblatex)
>   Using fallback language 'english' on input line 24.
>
> ! Package biblatex Error: Language 'english' not found.
>
> See the biblatex package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.24 \begin{document}

This of course doesn't make a sense, as English is clearly supported by Biblatex. I've found that the issue was caused by a redefinition of the `\IfFileExists` command by `tex4ht`. It is used in the language loading in Biblatex for the language detection. The issue is that due the redefinition of `\IfFileExists` wrong code is skipped and code for both found and missing language is executed. So even if the language is found and loaded, the error message is shown.

The fix has already been posted to the `tex4ht` repository and it is included in TL. An alternative version of the `\blx@lbxinput@iii` must be used in the `usepackage.4ht` file. It must be used here instead of `biblatex.4ht`, because the Biblatex language loading happens before normal `.4ht` files are loaded, so it would have no effect in `biblatex.4ht`.

```
\def\blx@lbxinput@iii#1#2{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lng@#2}%
  \:IfFileExists{#1.lbx}
    {\blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#1}{language '#2' -> '#1'}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@suffmaptried@#2}
      {}
      {\blx@warning@noline{%
          File '#1.lbx' not found!\MessageBreak
          Ignoring mapping '#2' -> '#1'}%
       \global\cslet{blx@suffmaptried@#2}\@empty}%
     \blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#2}{language '#2'}}}
```

The only difference from the `Biblatex` sources is the use of `\:IfFileExists` instead of `\IfFileExists`. It contains the original code of `\IfFileExists` so it doesn't cause the wrong code execution.

[image]

Comment: +1. Interestingly the error about English not being supported does not occur when `biblatex` is used directly instead of the wrapper `biblatex-chicago`. And I really don't understand why the redefined `\IfFileExists` would fail so spectacularly...

Comment: @moewe it seems that it happens especially with language mappings.

Comment: @moewe it caused `\expandafter\@firstoftwo` to skip code appended to `\IfFileExists` instead of the error messages.

Comment: @michal.h21  Just a small updation, please remove the `}` at the last line of the `biblatex.4ht` which you mentioned in your answer...apology for the so late in checking

Comment: @MadyYuvi which version of `biblatex.4ht` do you mean? there is no `}` in the distributed version.

Comment: @michal.h21 Sorry, it is correct in all distribution, I meant that the answer you gave above...

Comment: @MadyYuvi ah I see it now